# Automatically re-login after session expires

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat

When a Tomcat session expires, I'd like to identify who was previously logged in, and process a login automatically without displaying the login page.

This is what I'm thinking:

1. During a login, store the user name along with the session ID (from `HttpsSession.getId()`) in an application variable.
2. If a connection comes in without a valid session, use `HttpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId()` to get the previous session ID.
3. If there was a previous session ID, check it against the stored list; if found, then process a login for the associated user.

I know this won't resurrect the expired session's data, which is ok, I only want to know the user name.

Is this a reasonable approach?  Or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you simply make your session expire time longer?

Comment: I want to be able to do the automatic re-login regardless of how long the session has been idle (potentially days), but I don't want to leave the entire session active for that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could make use of Tomcat's `org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager` which can swap idle sessions out to persistent storage (disk/database). Then you could make your session expire time much longer without the worry of long running sessions hanging around in memory. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html